# Owl Carousel is not working for Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, instagram

I am trying to get carousel using owl-carousel which is working fine for some module but,i am trying to get instagram post giving limit to use carousel but its not working Below is my code.

Script.min.js

```
 var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    limit: 4,
    accessToken: "XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    userId: XXXXXX,
    target: "homeInstagramWrapper",
    filter: function(image) {
      image.timeAgoInWords = moment(image.created_time * 1000).fromNow();
      return image;
    },
    template: '<div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-inspirations"><a class="instagram-image" href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{model.images.low_resolution.url}}" /></a></div>'
  } );
  feed.run();
```

My another code :

LandingPage.php

```
  <div class="instagram-wrapper track-all-links" data-sm-network="instagram">
              <h3><i class="bits-sm-icon-instagram-black"></i> Instagram <a href="https://instagram.com/XXXXX" target="_blank" class="text-gray">XXX</a></h3>
                <div id="homeInstagramWrapper">
                </div>
 </div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery("#owl-inspirations").owlCarousel({
    items : 2,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true,
    pagination : false,
    navigationText: [
        '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev"  id="left-button">Previous</button>',
        '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" id="right-button">Next</button>'
    ],

});
});
</script>
```

Using id 'owl-inspiration' is not able to call jquery in landing page from script.min.js.Is there any solution for this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks